Why did some of my internal drives start getting detected as ejectable and removable?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel is "6.9.3-76060903-generic"). A couple of days ago I did a software update (apt update && apt upgrade) and rebooted, and now several of my internal drives,
including /home have eject buttons next to them in Nautilus (GNOME FIles).
From querying Gio.VolumeMonitor using Python, I can see that the issue seems
to be caused by the these volumes being listed as both ejectable and removable.
Prior to the update at least one of these was false — I think both were.
I'm not sure which component's update caused this new behavior. I also don't
know if this is a new bug, or if it's an intentional behavior change.
Here's what the relevant lines in my fstab look like:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/... /home auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/... /mnt/foo auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Foo 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/... /mnt/bar auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Bar 0 0

I do want these drives to show up in Nautilus, but I don't want them to
have eject buttons.
How can I get these drives to not be listed as ejectable or removable, but
still have them appear in the left nav of Nautilus?

Add your kernel info to the question.

@KhalidAbuShawarib I've added it: 6.9.3-76060903-generic. Let me know if any other info would be helpful. Thanks.

Linux Kernel was reporting SATA hot-plug devices as ejectable since 6.9, but was fixed in version 6.9.6.
Source:

https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/1282
https://lore.kernel.org/regressions/c0de8262-dc4b-4c22-9fac-33432e5bddd3@t-8ch.de/
https://lwn.net/Articles/979263/

